# JMS session commit on Spring Application shutdown

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-jms

I am using Spring Boot, Integration and JMS with ActiveMQ. I am consuming messages from a queue with jms:inbound-gateway. Following scenarios occur:

a) message is delivered and application performs action and when finished, session is committed and message is consumed and result is sent.

b) message is delivered and error occurs, session is rolled back and message will be redelivered

c) message is delivered and application is shut down. The jms session is **committed** and message is lost because the application never was able to send the result due to shutdown.

c) is the problem

Could anyone tell me why there is a commit on shutdown or if I can change this behavior to rollback ? No configuration that I tried changes this behavior.

Thanks

Comment: The commit will only occur if the listener thread exits normally; normally, the in-flight operation will complete normally. If the shutdown causes some problem for the in-flight message, it must throw an exception to force a rollback; if it exits normally without having performed the necessary tasks, it will be committed.

Comment: I told you on Gitter: your configuration would be really helpful. Plus, be sure that you don't shift message to another thread.